isoperimetric theorem for pyramids and cones
I know that a cylinder maximizes its volume for a given surface area when a vertical cross section that passes through its center is a square (as opposed to an oblong rectangle) and am assuming the same principle is true for a cone (that it maximizes its volume for a given surface area when the cross section passing through its apex is an equilateral triangle, as opposed to a different isosceles triangle) but wanted to double check.


Looking at pyramids, does the maximum volume happen when a lateral face is an equilateral triangle or when a vertical cross section passing through the apex (red) is an equilateral triangle?  I don't think they can both be equilateral triangles since two sides of the red cross section are heights of the lateral faces and the ratio of an equilateral triangle's side to its height is $2\!:\!\sqrt{3}$.

I don’t think your assumption about the cone is true. Please try it out yourself and include your attempts in the post.

There's something quite interesting in the pyramid case. You give examples of square pyramids, which as you note have two likely candidates for the "correct" isosceles triangle to be looking at (a triangle through two non-adjacent base vertices and the apex, or a triangle through two non-adjacent midpoints of base edges and the apex). But have you thought about the case where the base has an odd number of sides? I suppose there's a unique isosceles triangle with the apex as a vertex and edges on the faces of the pyramid, but I'm not sure if that's the triangle we're interested in...

...[cont.] For the cone, as @Pranay points out, I don't think we're looking at an equilateral triangle. As they suggest, please could you add your efforts to your post? At the moment, I'm looking at a Lagrangian multiplier approach for the general pyramid problem, but I'm not sure if you're familiar with that. (My preference would be to use something more elementary but I haven't found anything yet!) In fact, it should be doable with differential calculus but the algebra gets a bit messy.

@ChrisLewis I agree that the algebra is a bit messy (I used wolfram alpha to do it) but it can certainly be done using calculus. One can solve the constraint for one of the two variables and substitute it in the quantity we are trying to maximize, which then depends only on one variable. Of course, this can be repeated for pyramids of other bases too.

For a cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$, the total area is:
$$
A = 2\pi r(r+h)
$$
and the volume is:
$$
V = \pi r^2h
$$
so at fixed area, the maximal volume is reached with $h = 2r$ i.e. a share cross section as you claimed.
However, as remarked in the comments, your starting point for the cone is wrong. For a cone of radius $r$ and height $h$, the total area is:
$$
A = \pi r(r+\sqrt{r^2+h^2})
$$
and the volume:
$$
V = \frac13\pi r^2h
$$
It is simpler to do the math by varying the apotheme $L=\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$ instead of $h$. The maximal volume is reached when $L = 3R$. In terms of height, this means that $h = 2\sqrt 2 r$. The cross section passing through the axis is therefore not an equilateral triangle, but rather an isosceles triangle of ratio $3:2$ (you were not too far off by assuming that it was equilateral).
For a pyramid whose basis is a regular polygon, with $n$ sides, apotheme $a$ and height $h$, the area is:
$$
A = n\tan\left(\frac\pi n\right)a\left(a+\sqrt{a^2+h^2}\right)
$$
and the volume:
$$
V = \frac13n\tan\left(\frac\pi n\right)a^2h
$$
Mathematically, you can reduce to the previous problem with $r\to a$. There is no need to do the same math twice, and you get the ratio:
$$
h = 2\sqrt 2 a
$$
or in terms of the apotheme (of the pyramid) $L = \sqrt{h^2+a^2}$:
$$
L = 3a
$$
Therefore, half of the red triangle is always the same rectangle triangle ratio $1:3:2\sqrt2$ no matter the number of sides of the polygon and in particular the limit when it becomes a circle. In particular, for even sided polygons, the cross section is the same red isosceles triangle of ratio $2:3:3$.
